# Simpler Way to Add a new Field to Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a field in animal_food (a json object) called `treats` and I want to add a field in treats called `time_eaten` and then return everything from the field treats.

```
 def addTime(time)
    animal_food["treats"]["time_eaten"] = time
    animal_food["treats"]
  end
```

Is there a way I can do the code above in 1 line (using merge or other ruby syntax?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
animal_food['treats'].merge!({'time_eaten' => time})
```

does the same thing as those two lines. (Note the exclamation mark.) You could also say

```
animal_food['treats'].tap { |treats| treats['time_eaten'] = time }
```

Or, in Ruby 2.7 preview, using numbered parameters:

```
animal_food['treats'].tap { @1['time_eaten'] = time }
```